# R using different data frame column conditions to populate new column

Tags: r

I have the following dataframes:
The first is node_data:

```
structure(list(Ids = 1426:1431, Grade.and.Class = c("5B", "5B", 
"5B", "5B", "5B", "5B"), color = c("darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray", 
"darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray"), onset = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), terminus = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf), newid = 1:6, 
    Status.Day1 = c("Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
    "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible"), Status.Day2 = c("Susceptible", 
    "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
    "Susceptible")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

the second is edge_data:

```
   structure(list(time_start = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), time_end = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Person.1 = c(1558L, 1560L, 1567L, 1632L, 1632L, 
    1673L), Person.2 = c(1567L, 1570L, 1574L, 1818L, 1866L, 1698L
    ), attrs = c("3B-3B", "3B-3B", "3B-3B", "4B-4B", "4B-4B", "1B-1B"
    ), temp_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), temp_ing = c(1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1), from = c(59L, 60L, 64L, 86L, 86L, 103L), to = c(64L, 
    65L, 67L, 191L, 215L, 116L), Stats.day1 = c("Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
    "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible"), 
        newly.exposedday1 = c("No", "No", "No", "No", "No", "No")), row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to do the following:
for each newid in the node_data dataframe, look in edge_data$newly.exposedday1, if the value in newid from the node_data is there, change Status.Day2 in the node_data to "I".  I would also like to change the Status.Day2 to "I" if the newid is also in node_data$Status.Day1

Thanks!

Comment: How can `node_data$newid`, a numeric variable be in `edge_data$newly.exposedday1`? And the same for `node_data$newid` in `node_data$Status.Day1`.

Comment: `edge_data$newly.exposedday1` is a character vector with all `"No"`, and `node_data$newid` is integers. They have nothing in common. If this is known, then (1) checking integers for string membership or the other way around indicates some problems with your data-plan; or (2) who knows, I can think of no reason why this would be valid.

Comment: Natalie, including the data with `dput` is good, thank you for providing clear data. Unfortunately, what you're asking for seems counter-intuitive. Please [edit] your question and either correct the typos or clarify clearly why different class variables would be matched in this way. (And then provide sample data that actually provides at least one match.)

Answer (score 0):

Next time, please consider giving at least one record of the situations you are describing. I have modified your MWE as shown below:

```
node_data <- structure(list(Ids = 1426:1431, Grade.and.Class = c("5B", "5B", "5B", "5B", "5B", "5B"),
               color = c("darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray", 
                         "darkgray", "darkgray", "darkgray"), 
               onset = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               terminus = c(Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf, Inf), newid = 1:6,
               Status.Day1 = c("Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
                               "Susceptible", 5, "Susceptible"),
               Status.Day2 = c("Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
                               "Susceptible","Susceptible")), 
          row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
          class = "data.frame")

edge_data <- structure(list(time_start = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      time_end = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
                      Person.1 = c(1558L, 1560L, 1567L, 1632L, 1632L, 1673L),
                      Person.2 = c(1567L, 1570L, 1574L, 1818L, 1866L, 1698L), 
                      attrs = c("3B-3B", "3B-3B", "3B-3B", "4B-4B", "4B-4B", "1B-1B" ),
                      temp_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                      temp_ing = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                      from = c(59L, 60L, 64L, 86L, 86L, 103L), 
                      to = c(64L, 65L, 67L, 191L, 215L, 116L), 
                      Stats.day1 = c("Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible"),
                      newly.exposedday1 = c("No", "No", "No", 3, "No", 4)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, 6L), 
                 class = "data.frame")
```

I think this is what you are expecting:

```
dt1names <- names(node_data)

dt <- merge(node_data,edge_data,by=NULL) %>% 
  mutate(Status.Day2 = ifelse((newid %in% Status.Day1 | newid %in%  newly.exposedday1), "Inf", Status.Day2)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(all_of(dt1names)) %>% distinct()

> dt
   Ids Grade.and.Class    color onset terminus newid Status.Day1 Status.Day2
1 1426              5B darkgray     0      Inf     1 Susceptible Susceptible
2 1427              5B darkgray     0      Inf     2 Susceptible Susceptible
3 1428              5B darkgray     0      Inf     3 Susceptible         Inf
4 1429              5B darkgray     0      Inf     4 Susceptible         Inf
5 1430              5B darkgray     0      Inf     5           5         Inf
6 1431              5B darkgray     0      Inf     6 Susceptible Susceptible
```